# How to install RHEL source code RPM in non-default directory?

Tags: linux, rhel, rpm, rpmbuild

The `RHEL` source code RPM package is installed in `~/rpmbuild` by default. I want use `--prefix` option to change the installed directory:

```
[root@nan nan]# rpm -ivvh --prefix=/home/nan kernel-3.10.0-290.el7.src.rpm
D: ============== kernel-3.10.0-290.el7.src.rpm
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:0x401
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages 0x400 mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name 0x400 mode=0x0
D: Expected size:     82747446 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(82747166)
D:   Actual size:     82747446
D: kernel-3.10.0-290.el7.src.rpm: Header SHA1 digest: OK (96b97dc2dc445b69a5337a0df2c51aad0ec90e10)
D:      added source package [0]
D: found 1 source and 0 binary packages
D: Expected size:     82747446 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(82747166)
D:   Actual size:     82747446
D: kernel-3.10.0-290.el7.src.rpm: Header SHA1 digest: OK (96b97dc2dc445b69a5337a0df2c51aad0ec90e10)
Updating / installing...
   1:kernel-3.10.0-290.el7            ################################# [100%]
D: ========== Directories not explicitly included in package:
D:          0 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
D:          1 /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/
D: ==========
......
```

The source code is still installed in `~/rpmbuild` directory. How can I change the installed directory?

Answer (score 0):

--prefix works only with relocatable packages, to change destination directory for binary files

In your case, you should use --buildroot parameter instead.

Comment: It doesn't work: rpm: `--buildroot=/home/nan: unknown option`.

Comment: It should work when used with one of --bX parameters, check this link for the details: http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html

Comment: What is the meaning of `--bX`? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, -bX, not --bX - and this means -bs, -ba etc. as explained in the below link.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! But `RPM` in my `RHEL7` doesn't have `--buildroot` nor `-bX` options. Its options are here:[https://gist.github.com/NanXiao/3cc7283c7eba05f2cedb](https://gist.github.com/NanXiao/3cc7283c7eba05f2cedb).